# How to count how many times an entity appears with another entity

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6], [4, 7]], columns=['group_id', 'student_id'])
```

Each `student_id` can appear multiple times in different `group_id`s with others `student_id`s.

I want to count how many times student `x` was in the same group as student `y`.
In other words, I want a n x n DF where each entry is the number of times 2 students have been on the same group (same `group_id`, when no match, fill with 0).

```
2 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 1 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 1    
7 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Any way I can do it in a cleaver way with SQL or Pandas?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post pictures. Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do with `numpy` `outer`

```
s = df.group_id.to_numpy()
yourdf = pd.DataFrame(np.equal.outer(s,s),index=df.student_id,columns=df.student_id).astype(int)
yourdf
Out[40]: 
student_id  2  3  6  7
student_id            
2           1  1  0  0
3           1  1  0  0
6           0  0  1  1
7           0  0  1  1
```

Or do

```
freq = pd.crosstab(df['group_id'],df['student_id'])
yourdf = freq.T.dot(freq)
Out[45]: 
student_id  2  3  6  7
student_id            
2           1  1  0  0
3           1  1  0  0
6           0  0  1  1
7           0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

you can `merge` and then `pivot_table`:

```
df_ = (df.merge(df, on='group_id')
         .pivot_table(index='student_id_x', columns='student_id_y', 
                      values='group_id', aggfunc='nunique').fillna(0)
         .astype(int)
      )
print (df_)
student_id_y  2  3  6  7
student_id_x            
2             1  1  0  0
3             1  1  0  0
6             0  0  1  1
7             0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# make dummy cols in the dataframe
df['student_id_2'] = df['student_id'].copy()
df['flag'] = 1

dx = (df
      .drop('group_id', 1)
      .set_index(['student_id', 'student_id_2'])
      .unstack(-1)
      .fillna(0))

# fix column names
dx.columns.names = None, None
dx.columns = [x[1] for x in dx.columns]

print(dx)
                            
                2    3    6    7
student_id                      
2             1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3             0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
6             0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
7             0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To present a more instructive example (better filled),
I prepared a bit bigger source DataFrame:

```
   group_id  student_id
0         1           2
1         1           3
2         2           2
3         2           6
4         3           3
5         3           2
6         4           6
7         4           7
```

To get the result, run:

```
stId = df.student_id.unique()
result = pd.DataFrame(0, index=stId, columns=stId)
for s1, s2 in df.groupby('group_id').student_id.apply(list):
    result.loc[s2, s1] += 1
    result.loc[s1, s2] += 1
```

When you print the result, you will get:

```
   2  3  6  7
2  0  2  1  0
3  2  0  0  0
6  1  0  0  1
7  0  0  1  0
```

As you can see:

- students *2* and *3* took part 2 times in the same group,
- student *6* was **once** in pair with student *2*,
- student *6* was **once** in pair with student *7*.

In my opinion, there is something wrong in each solution showing that
a student was in one group with himself.